# calculating DFT coefficient

Tags: r, math, fft

I have a time series and it contains 256 integer values. It looks like this:

[image]

I have calculated [STFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)( Short Time Forier Transform) whit this code in r:

```
s<-stft(datalist, win=min(80,floor(length(datalist)/10)), inc=min(24,floor(length(datalist)/30)), coef=256, wtype="hanning.window")
```

as a resault I have a matrix with 29 rows and 256 values. If I show one row of this matrix in a plot( i.e 10th row). I am seeing such a diagramm:

[image]

but I have this expectation, that the coefficient diagram should look like the first diagramm?(only in another dimension)

should I use another package in R to do this job? or my understood is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the `stft` function from [package GENEArerad](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GENEAread/index.html). In your case, the call is basically

```
s<-stft(datalist, win=25, inc=8, coef=256, wtype="hanning.window")
```

So the way I read it, you are taking 25 samples but computing 256 coefficients from this. The documentation states that the maximal (reasonable) value for `coef` is `win/2`, due to the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) I guess. So all but the first 12 or so coefficients will be mostly bogus. And those first few coefficients are off the scale of your plot, so we can't say anything about these either.

I don't know where your expectation did come from, and I don't share it. But I also believe there are some more fundamental problems with how you expect this to work.